# How can I take the value of an Input and store it in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I have a problem trying to take the information submitted in an input and return it as output outside the nav component, where it sits. I want the output to return to the Content component but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do that. Trying to return it as a prop returns as undefined. I have read the documentation and tried to find answer in videos but nothing seems to be solving the problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
// this is the root component 
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userInput: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {

    const { userInput } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="recipes">
        <Nav />
        <Content userInput={this.state.userInput} changed={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// this is where the input is stored and where I want to take its value and return it to the the Content Component
class Nav extends React.Component {

    state = {
        userInput: ''
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            userInput: e.target.value
        })
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <nav className="nav">
                <h1 className="title" >Nourish</h1>
                <h2 className="title" >{this.state.userInput}</h2>
                <input type="text" className="input" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

// this is where I want to output the value to
const Content = (props) => {
    console.log(props.userInput)

    return (
        <h2 className="main"> {props.userInput} </h2>
    )
}
```

Comment: You only need to store the userInput in the App class. Provide the Nav class with a callback function, when the input is updated, use that function to update the state in App. Than provice the same state value to the Content class as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a simple input component but the value and event handlers come from the parent as props
look at this example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Input from './Input'

const App = () => {
    const [InputOneValue, setInputOnValue] = useState("")
    const [InputTwoValue, setInputTwoValue] = useState("")
    
    const InputOneChangeHandler = (value) => {
        setInputOneValue(value) 
    }  
    const InputTwoChangeHandle = (value) => {
        setInputTwoValue(value)
    }

    const onSubmitHanlder = () {
      // InputOneValue
      // InputTwoValue
    }    
 
    return (
       <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
           <Input value={InputOneValue} changeHandler={InputOneChangeHandler}
           <Input value={InputTwoValue} changeHandler={InputTwoChangeHandler}
       </form>
    )
}

export default App
```

and this is you Input component

```
  const Input = (props) => {
      return <input value={props.value} onChange={props.changeHandler} />
  }
  
  export default Input
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write handle change and not needed to store userInput in Nav. store directly in App.js . so in Nav instead of `this.handleChange` use `this.props.changed` this helps you store userInput in App then you can pass the data as props.

```
// this is the root component 
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userInput: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {

    const { userInput } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="recipes">
        <Nav userInput={this.state.userInput} />
        <Content userInput={this.state.userInput} changed={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <nav className="nav">
                <h1 className="title" >Nourish</h1>
                <h2 className="title" >{this.state.userInput}</h2>
                <input type="text" className="input" onChange={this.props.changed} />
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

// this is where I want to output the value to
const Content = (props) => {
    console.log(props.userInput)
    return (
        <h2 className="main"> {props.userInput} </h2>
    )
}
```